# Python : Interpretation of plotted lines from pandas (possible interpolation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm working on this dataframe:

```
    0 B  30 B      60 B  90 B
0   0.0  0.80  1.000000   2.0
1   0.5  1.00  1.300000   2.5
3   0.7  1.30  1.700000   3.0
5   0.8  1.50  2.033333   3.5
10  1.0  1.75  2.383333   4.0
13  1.3  1.99  2.733333   4.3
15  1.5  2.23  3.083333   4.5
20  2.0  2.50  3.433333   5.0
25  2.5  3.00  3.783333   5.5
30  3.0  3.30  4.133333   6.0
```

I used it to plot the following curves, where each column represent a line, the index of the dataframe is the x-axis and values from the dataframe are the y-axis. To do that I just used the simple following line :

```
  data.plot()
```

Here are the plotted curves :

[image: Curves]

Now i'm trying to be able to plot points on this graph. I would like to be able to plot the point if the user gives a value for x-axis and a "B value" (for example on the graph, the red point has a "B value" of 90) even if this value has not a ploted curves (ex: 45) .

I've thought about using interpolation between closer lines but I don't really know how to do that. I've searched for similar cases in forums but didn't find anything.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The cooridnate of the red point is `(8, 3.8)` I'm not clear on what you want

Comment: I want to get the Y-axis value of the point (here it's 3.8) if the user decide to plot a point with a X-axis value and a "B_value" as input ( for our example it could be X=8 and B=90 but i'd like to be able to do that also if the "B_value" given is not plotted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to be able to interpolate **both** X-values and the B-values. Because of this your current representation gets a little confusing. I think it's more natural to make those your axes and then have color represent the third dimension.

If you know you will only ever need integer values, you could `reindex` both axes then interpolate across them. There are a lot of choices to be made with interpolation. Here's a dummy way to do each separately, just to illustrate the mechanics.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fix column names
df.columns = [int(x[0]) for x in df.columns.str.split()]
df = df.reindex(range(0,max(df.columns)+1), axis=1).reindex(range(0, max(df.index)+1))

df_i = df.interpolate(axis=1).interpolate()

# To get a value (X, B)
df_i.loc[7, 45]
#1.8866665000000002

# For plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(df_i.T)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel("B")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This type of interpolation is can also be done more properly with `scipy`. Starting over from your original DataFrame:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

df.columns = [int(x[0]) for x in df.columns.str.split()]

# Get arrays for all valid values:
s = df.stack()
x = s.index.get_level_values(0).to_numpy()
y = s.index.get_level_values(1).to_numpy()
z = s.to_numpy()

# Grid on which you want to interpolate data
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(range(0, max(df.index)+1), range(0, max(df.columns)+1))

# Interpolate
sp = interpolate.griddata(np.array(list(zip(x,y))), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

# Same point as above, 
sp[45, 7]
#1.9066665000000003
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying that :) what is the s variable ?

Comment: @AlexJJ sorry, that should be `s = df.stack()`

Comment: I'm getting an error on the sp[45, 7] :      IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: This error seems to occure only if i enter a float ( for ex : sp[45, 7.5]

Comment: @AlexJJ yes, `sp` is an array, so you can only index it by integers. If you want a finer spacing, you'll need to modify the spacing in the `np.meshgrid` step. But then to select X=12, you'll need to be more careful, because index `12` wont correspond to X=12 (i.e. if you spacing is 0.5, you'd need to select index 24)